# Why when I call a closure it executes a nested function?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am learning closures and I have two questions.

From what I've read about closures:

- Closures are used only when program has nested functions
- Closures are used to assign the return value of nested function

First question:

Is my understanding about closures right?

```
def hi(x):
   print(x)
   def hh():
      print(x)
      return x

   return hh
hi(9)

hj=hi(12)
hj11=hi(99)

print(hj())
print(hj11())
```

Second question:
Why is the nested function being called every time I call `hj()` or `hj11()` ?

I am confused that if the closure is assigning to the main function `(hj=hi ,  hj11=hi)`, then why is it calling the nested function whenever I call `hj()`?

Comment: Calling `hi()` returned a function object (a new function object each time, from the `def hh(): ...` statement in `hi()`). That function object uses a closure to get at the value of `x`. I'm not sure what you expected to happen instead?